# I am having a problem connecting my Pi 3B to the internet wirelessly

Tags: internet

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3.

When it prompted me to connect to my internet I entered the password but it just displayed failed to connect. So I tried an Ethernet cable and it worked, but I want it to be wireless.

What can I do?

Comment: are you sure you have entered the correct ssid and password?  Perhaps you can try them on your mobile phone with the same ssid and password.

Comment: Can you connect to the same Wi-Fi network using another device (PC, iPhone etc)?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to reconfigure WiFi. Just create a file `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` similar to this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="wlan@hoeft-online.de"
    psk="verySecretPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Of course you have to use your own settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=`.

Then reboot and look if it works. The file should have been removed.